# OBIEE 12.2.1.2 - Restore RPD from an earlier saved copy of the RPD

Tags: oracle, repository, business-intelligence, obiee, backup-strategies

the topic at hand is creating periodic data backups and data security.

**1. RPD**

OBIEE 11:

- Save copies of the RPD locally.
- Possibility to deploy RPDs within the Enterprise Manager.

OBIEE 12:

- Save copies of the RPD locally.
- No possibility to deploy RPDs within the Enterprise Manager.

  - Is this option no longer available?

**2. RPD and everything else**

Another option I can think of, is creating backups with "export/importServiceInstance": resulting in saving everything (rpd,webcat,conpools,...).

Ideas and suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, with OBIEE 12c you do not have the option to deploy RPD from EM. Instead you can use the command line utility tool `datamodel.sh`/`datamodel.cmd`.

Using this tool you can download and upload OBIEE RPD and no restart is required. See [Upload Repository Command](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/biee/BIEMG/GUID-C0BBA452-CC54-43A3-9A61-F1ADCCBEBDDB.htm#upload_repos_cmd).

Comment: Hey Sherry. Do I have to put up with you in here as well now? ;-)

Comment: Hi Christian, You are everywhere!! Hopefully I'll not cause too much trouble here :)